# Return the content of a Wildcard match in Python

Tags: python, regex, wildcard

Is it possible to return the contents that match a wildcard (like .*) in a regex pattern in Python?

For example, a match like:

```
re.search('stack.*flow','stackoverflow')
```

would return the string 'over'.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a capturing group:

```
>>> import re
>>> re.search('stack(.*)flow', 'stackoverflow').group(1)
'over'
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can *capture* your result. For this, just use the `()`

```
matchobj = re.search('stack(.*)flow','stackoverflow') 
print(matchobj.group(1)) # => over
```